# Returning an NSRectangle with Equal width and height

Tags: macos, swift4, core-image

I use the following code to return an NSRectangle

```
  let ciimage = ciImage.cropped(to: $0.bounds.insetBy(dx: -$0.bounds.width/1.6, dy: -$0.bounds.width/1.6) )
```

But the returned rectangle has unequal width and height.How can i make it a square?

Answer (score 0):

```
let width = $0.bounds.width; let height = $0.bounds.height
let widthInset = (width > height) ? (width - height) / 2 : 0
let heightInset = (height > width) ? (height - width) / 2 : 0
let croppedBounds = $0.bounds.insetBy(dx: widthInset, dy: heightInset)
ciImage = ciImage.cropped(to: croppedBounds)
```

Something like that?

Comment: Thanks .... but this produces a white border at the bottom of the image.

Comment: Please take a look at the bottom of this image https://imgur.com/a/FgNcCjv

Comment: Hmm, it seems like a rounding issue (half-pixel sizes get round up). Also, the image isn't square...